# Wrong function name mangling

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, name-mangling

I have a static library exporting the function

```
time_t SomeClass::getTime();
```

After compilation its name is mangled as

```
?getTime@SomeClass@@QAE_JXZ
```

When I try to use it, VS returns an error

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall SomeClass::getTime(void)" (?getTime@SomeClass@@QAEJXZ)
```

And I don't know what is wrong. Why the same function is mangled differently? I've compiled both projects with the same Visual Studio, class has a single header.

Please, help.

Comment: Which of this 2? Library from first is an external source for second project. I didn't change headers after last build of library.

Comment: Check, whether the member function declaration and definition really match, including the member function `const` qualifiers...

Comment: @Paul Michalik: That was the first what I checked.

Comment: @PavelOgnev Then check, whether the calling conventions are compatible. The linker appears to be looking for `__thiscall`, did you setup your projects to use other calling conventions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in difference in `time_t` declarations. Library means it is 64-bit, but application waits for 32-bit value.

The remaining question is "why there is no good documentation for MSVS name mangling"? I've read a lot, but didn't find what is the underline in parameters list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the .lib file in your linker INPUT property?
In the case you have both two projects in the same solution, you can add the library as a reference to the main project: right click in the main project, and References.

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, I've included them. Other functions from the library has worked but this is surprisingly "not defined".

Comment: I have this projects in different solutions. This library is a part of SDK i develop, so I'm trying to act like an its user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the whole project.
If this does not work, check your Visual Studio Directories (header, libs)